# Excel SUMIF between dates

Tags: excel, date, sumifs

I have column A with date values formatted as `mm/dd/yyyy`.  I am trying to sum the values of column B if A >=DATE(2012,1,1) AND

`=SUM(B:B)` sums B properly, but if I try to use `=SUMIF(B:B,A:A>=DATE(2012,1,1))` the value returned is `0.00`.  I'm assuming this has something to do with using decimal for the sum and date type for the criteria.  Is there a way to get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You haven't got your `SUMIF` in the correct order - it needs to be range, criteria, sum range. Try:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,">="&DATE(2012,1,1),B:B)
```

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb now.  Thanks.  My issue with the SUMIFS was I forgot the quotes around the >= and the < for the between dates.

Comment: @Crazy Horse also have a look at this question..http://stackoverflow.com/q/39937769/3496570

Answer (score 28):

To SUMIFS between dates, use the following:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&DATE(2012,1,1),A:A,"<"&DATE(2012,6,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to work around this issue that I thought I would share.

In my case I had a years worth of daily columns (i.e. Jan-1, Jan-2... Dec-31), and I had to extract totals for each month. I went about it this way: Sum the entire year, Subtract out the totals for the dates prior and the dates after. It looks like this for February's totals:

```
=SUM($P3:$NP3)-(SUMIF($P$2:$NP$2, ">2/28/2014",$P3:$NP3)+SUMIF($P$2:$NP$2, "<2/1/2014",$P3:$NP3))
```

Where `$P$2:$NP$2` contained my date values and `$P3:$NP3` was the first row of data I am totaling.
So `SUM($P3:$NP3)` is my entire year's total and I subtract (the sum of two `sumif`s):

`SUMIF($P$2:$NP$2, ">2/28/2014",$P3:$NP3)`, which totals all the months after February and 
`SUMIF($P$2:$NP$2, "<2/1/2014",$P3:$NP3)`, which totals all the months before February.

Answer (score 0):

this works, and can be adapted for weeks or anyother frequency i.e. weekly, quarterly etc...

=SUMIFS(B12:B11652,A12:A11652,">="&DATE(YEAR(C12),MONTH(C12),1),A12:A11652,"<"&DATE(YEAR(C12),MONTH(C12)+1,1))

Answer (score -1):

One more solution when you want to use data from any sell ( in the key `C3`)

```
=SUMIF(Sheet6!M:M;CONCATENATE("<";TEXT(C3;"dd.mm.yyyy"));Sheet6!L:L)
```