# Sum of Column values based on a particular row(person)

Tags: excel, ms-office

> Sum of values in Column B based on specific value in Column A.

**I am a new bee. So bear with me plx**

For example: If we select `Oct-2016` in Column A it gives us sum of all numeric in `Column B or Column C or Column D`.

I  want to *sum all the details* of Oct-2016 of a particular person.

See it on [**Google drive**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t9qRa51g--KOdkNw6wHLlXxq0p6TafMLmEJABiiJYWU/edit?usp=sharing)

**What have i tried...**
=SUMIF(B2:B32,DATE(2016,10,0),SUM(B2,B32)

Also tried

`=SUMIF(B2:B32,"="&DATE(2016,10,1),G2:G32)`// but my date doesn't contain day

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: you need http://stackoverflow.com/a/14464192/3496570

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Excel, sum all values in one column in each row where another column is a specific value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463955/in-excel-sum-all-values-in-one-column-in-each-row-where-another-column-is-a-spe)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057010/excel-sumif-between-dates

Answer (score 0):

[Test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tggd1.jpg)
[Test2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhj1U.jpg)

```
=IF(B3=$K$2,C3,0)
```

You may try this formula as updated in the image to resolve the problem quick.
Thanks.